# Unable to create DockerFile in Powershell Command

Tags: docker, powershell, asp.net-core

I am unable to create DockerFile in Powershell. The command I am using is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
```

The error I am getting is:

```
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
```

Here is the screenshot of it.
[image]

You can clearly see I am running the command from the app directory which is: "D:\Website\Project\Dockers\App".

I am following the official microsoft docs for it. [The link is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows#create-the-dockerfile).

I have dockers desktop installed in running. It is running in **Linux Containers** mode.

What is wrong, something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell is not Docker, and PowerShell won't be able to parse or understand docker commands.

If you want to *write* a dockerfile from PowerShell, do like you would to write any other text file:

```
"FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1" |Add-Content .\Dockerfile
```